# Change the REGEX paramater so it can work with number values too

Tags: google-sheets

I used the following formula for column A in my sheet.

```
=REGEXMATCH(A2, TEXTJOIN("|", 1,   FILTER(INDIRECT("Semi-Blacklist!A:A"),  INDIRECT("Semi-Blacklist!D:D")=FALSE)))
```

It works because column A in semi-blacklist is both numbers and letters. Column B is only numbers. So if I try this for column B:

```
=REGEXMATCH(B2, TEXTJOIN("|", 1,   FILTER(INDIRECT("Semi-Blacklist!B:B"),  INDIRECT("Semi-Blacklist!D:D")=FALSE)))
```

It doesn't work, and I get an error

> Function REGEXMATCH parameter 1 expects text values. But '123456789' is a number and cannot be coerced to a text

Is there a way to keep the same formula or at least a similar one, but change the parameter so it will work even if the B2 is only numbers?

Comment: You could use the MATCH instead of REXMATCH which avoids regular matching search

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=REGEXMATCH(B2&"", TEXTJOIN("|", 1,   
 FILTER(INDIRECT("Semi-Blacklist!B:B"),  INDIRECT("Semi-Blacklist!D:D")=FALSE)))
```

regex supports only plain text. numeric numbers needs to be converted to plain text